# Easy way to maintain scroll position with ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there was a way to easily maintain scroll position using MVC? I've seen a few ways of doing it with javascript, but I would like an easy way like webforms, such as the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack page property. Does such a thing exist or am I going to have to use javascript?

Comment: MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack uses javascript to implement that functionality under the hood.

Comment: @ToddSmith: Is there any place I can find the implementation for that? I need to replicate that feature without ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - there's nothing built into MVC - you need javascript

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, even though that's what I didn't want to hear :(

Answer (score 1):

[Maintain Scroll Position of EVERY Element on PostBacks | [Mostly] Technical Notes by Mahdi Hasheminezhad](http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver)